# Why are the layer-tree-layer source attributes absolute even if my project is set to relative paths?

Tags: qgis, file-path

When I save a group as a layer definition file (both from the context menu and via the python api) the
layer-tree-layer source attribute is incorrectly absolute:
    `source="/Volumes/gis/master/Raster/filename.tif"`

while the maplayer datasource is correctly relative:
    `<datasource>./Raster/filename.tif</datasource>`

If I change the .qlr text file (of the layer definition) to set the layer-tree-layer source attribute to relative, the layer definition will fail to load.

If I change the .qgs xml text file (the project file) to set the layer-tree-layer source attribute to relative, the group will show up empty  (failing silently) when loading the project file.

Is this a bug?